Fit the margins in Rmarkdown with photo and text in YAML section
i have this YAML section in the Rmarkdown in R studio.
---
geometry: top=1cm , bottom= 2cm , left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm
header-includes:

- \PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,table}{xcolor}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \usepackage{float}

-  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
-  \pagestyle{fancy}
-  \fancyhf{}
-  \addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm}
-  \chead{ \textbf{this is my greatest Report ever } \\\textbf{Q4 2024}} \lhead{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=3cm]{myphoto.JPG}} 
-  \cfoot{  \textbf{this is my greatest Report ever } \\\textbf{Q4 2024}}  
-  \rfoot{\thepage} 
-  \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}} 
-  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
---



'```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
'```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

'```{r cars}
summary(cars)
'```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

'```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
'```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.




i want the photo to increase more and take advantage all the height of the header section.
Also the footer in the footer i want the text to change line and add at the right the current date.
How can i do it in R ?
To adjust the YAML section appropriately ?


You should provide some more details on your expectations here, e.g. "in the footer i want the text to change line". What do you mean with this? Can you show a draft of your expected output? Is there a link where we can access myphoto.JPG?
